# How to import an external function that needs to load external data from external R package to build my own package?

Tags: r, r-package

This is my first time to build an R package--`my_package` and I created a function, for example `my_function()`.

In `my_function()`, I imported another function named `external_function()` in package `external_package`, using `@importFrom external_package external_function`.

The matter is that this `external_function()` needs to load `external.RData` stored in `external_package/data/external.RData`, therefore when I test `my_package` and `used my_function`, it got my error [`Error: there is no dataset called external.RData`].

To solve this problem, I woodenly created a `my_package/data` folder and save those .RData files into my package and now `my_function()` works but I really think this is not a good way to build an R package since these .RData are large.

Thus, how to import an external function that needs to load external dataset from the external R package? Is there any way to fix this matter? Many thanks advanced.

Comment: Is the `external_package` an official CRAN package?

Comment: No actually, it should be downloaded and install manually.